# static_cast vs implicit cast

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, casting

I have a function `f` which will be called hundreds of millions of times, and I was wondering is there any runtime performance difference between:

```
void f()
{
    int a = ...;
    size_t b = static_cast<size_t>(a);
}
```

and

```
void f()
{
    int a = ...;
    size_t b = a;
}
```

I heard somwhere that `static_cast` has to create a temp variable, which means it has a small cost.

I was wondering if implicit casting has the same performance impact.

Or, is `static_cast` the same as `reinterpret_cast` where it has 0 extra instructions?

Comment: You can check the generated assembly on places like [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/). I'm seeing the two versions compiling to the same thing.

Comment: There is a nuance that the dupe doesn't address, namely if you `static_cast` to the same type as the implicit conversion, then there will be no difference whatsoever. But it *is* possible to generate additional code by `static_cast`ing to some unnatural type like `float` in this [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e8ceWK1jo).